# Running a Preloader only if content is not cached in the browser

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple jQuery preloader as follows:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $("#load-info").fadeOut();
            $("#preloader").delay(500).fadeOut("slow", function() {
                this.remove();
            });
        });
```

The preloader ID is a white background the entire height of the page, #load-info is the loading text and spinner. Upon completing the spinner and loading message fades out, and then the white background fades out and reveals the page content and the item is removed from the DOM. This works great, but I wanted to try taking it a step further and make it so the user won't see any of the preloader if they were simply refreshing or revisiting the page.

I know that I could simply remove the fades, but then when the preloader is actually necessary it would be too abrupt. I was thinking maybe a time stamp and checking to see if the time is longer than, let's say 500ms, run the preloader, otherwise just show the content... but I don't know if this is the correct way of doing this.

How would I run a preloader only when a page actually needs to be loaded and not on every page view, am I over-complicating this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be more complicated than what you're looking for, but you could check for the existence of a cookie during the server-side handling of the request. If the cookie does not exist, you know that the user is on the page for the first time and thus it is not cached. Then you set the cookie in the response, or set it in the JavaScript. If the cookie *does* exist, then you know not to show the pre-loader.